# Python loop getting stuck?

Tags: python, loops

The brute force search I'm trying to implement should iterate over the range of values, but it seems to be getting stuck. 
I'd ideally like to keep using for loops

I've tried reordering the for loops and using [Angle,Max_Camber,Max_Camber_Position,Thickness] directly instead of assigning it.

```
Iterations = -1
Current_Max = 0
Airfoil = [0, 1, 1, 10]

for Angle in range(Airfoil[0],90,15):   
    for Max_Camber in range(Airfoil[1],11,2):
        for Max_Camber_Position in range(Airfoil[2],11,2):
            for Thickness in range(Airfoil[3],100,20):

                Iterations+=1
                print("Iterations = ",Iterations)

                # Commenting this out stops the error
                # The loop should have 749 iterations rather than 17
                Airfoil =[Angle,Max_Camber,Max_Camber_Position,Thickness]
                print("Airfoil = ",  Airfoil)
```

Comment: Changing the object you're iterating while you're iterating it seems like a bad design choice.

Comment: Use a different variable name, e.g.`Airfoil2`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You're reassigning to the variable `Airfoil` so every time you get back to outer loop it's going to re-run the inner loops with new values of `Airfoil[1]` and so on.

Comment: `# The loop should have 749 iterations` - sure about this number?

Comment: @MikeScotty He is not changing the `range` objects he is iterating over.

Comment: @KlausD. the `range` expression for an inner loop is re-evaluated every time its parent loop runs.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog That is true, but it creates a new `range` object and does not change the existing one.

Comment: @KlausD. the point is that the new `range` is *different* to the old one (as `Airfoil` is constantly being updated), which gives an unexpected number of iterations.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog The point was "Changing the object you're iterating while you're iterating" and that never happened. No `range` object was changed.

Comment: @KlausD. ok I see your point. Ambiguous wording but a good piece of advice nonetheless for OP's skill level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you assign Airfoil with value
Airfoil =[Angle,Max_Camber,Max_Camber_Position,Thickness]
you actually changed iteration starting position

in order to get 749 iterations
change your print Airfoil to some name else like

```
Iterations = -1
Current_Max = 0
Airfoil = [0, 1, 1, 10]

for Angle in range(Airfoil[0],90,15):   
    for Max_Camber in range(Airfoil[1],11,2):
        for Max_Camber_Position in range(Airfoil[2],11,2):
            for Thickness in range(Airfoil[3],100,20):

                Iterations+=1
                print("Iterations = ",Iterations)
                Airfoil2 =[Angle,Max_Camber,Max_Camber_Position,Thickness]
                print("Airfoil = ",  Airfoil2)
```

this will work

Answer (score 0):

You should use a different variable name to create your list before printing it. You could also make use of Python's [`product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20product#itertools.product) function which helps with avoiding deeply nested for loops for doing exactly what you are doing, for example:

```
from itertools import product

Iterations = -1
Current_Max = 0
Airfoil = [0, 1, 1, 10]

for Angle, Max_Camber, Max_Camber_Position, Thickness in product(
    range(Airfoil[0], 90, 15), range(Airfoil[1], 11, 2), 
    range(Airfoil[2], 11, 2), range(Airfoil[3], 100, 20)):

    Iterations += 1
    print("Iterations = ", Iterations)

    Airfoil2 = [Angle, Max_Camber, Max_Camber_Position, Thickness]
    print("Airfoil = ",  Airfoil2)
```